# Convert the code from Foreach loop to Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, foreach

How to convert the following code from foreach loop into Linq ?

Code:

```
foreach (WorkItemLinkInfo item in testResults)
{
    var testitem = project.Store.GetTestItem(item.TestId);
    testItemList.Add(testitem);                                 
}
```

Comment: What is the testresults type?

Comment: @mrida, type is `(local variable)WorkItemLinkInfo[] testResults`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
testItemList = testResults.Select(item => 
                                 project.Store.GetTestItem(item.TestId))
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
testResults.Select(x=>project.Store.GetTestItem(x.TestId))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the LINQ version:

```
var testItemList = testResults.
 Select(item=> project.Store.GetTestItem(item.TestId)).
  ToList();
```

*For each test-result item, get test-item by test-result item's ID*

Answer (score 1):

```
testItemList.AddRange(testResults.Select(t => project.Store.GetTestItem(t.TestId)));
```

If you're creating `testItemList` just before this loop you can do:

```
var testItemList = testResults.Select(t => project.Store.GetTestItem(t.TestId)).ToList();
```